# How can calculate the sum of a column (but taking specific rows of it) in python using csv file?

Tags: python, csv, file, sum, calculated-columns

```
Level     ColumntoSum
1           4
2          10
1          3
2          23
1          15
2          2
```

So imagine this is my CSV file,it contains 2 columns [Level, ColumnToSum], in Level =[1,2,1,2,1,2] and ColumnToSum has random numbers next to each level.

What I need is to calculate the sum of "ColumntoSum" with Level=1 alone and the sum of level=2 alone then I need to save it in another CSV file in this way. (Having the 2nd column contains the sum of each level)

```
Level  Column
1       Sum1
2       Sum2
```

Comment: you could use dictionary with `Level` as key to sum it but it would need `for`-loop to read lines/rows from cvs. It would be much easier with `pandas`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your CSV file with `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('name_of_your_file.csv')
```

You can use `pandas` `groupby()` function to group them by `Level` and the `sum()` function to calculate the sum of each group as shown bellow:

```
df=df.groupby('Level').sum()
display(df)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
       ColumntoSum
Level             
1               22
2               35
```

Saving your data to CSV file:

```
df.to_csv('out.csv', index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupby(['Level']).sum()
```

This will generate your sum

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import csv

with open('data.csv') as fp:
    reader = csv.DictReader(fp)
    res = {}
    for row in reader:
        res.setdefault(row['Level'], []).append(int(row['ColumntoSum']))

with open('output.csv', 'w') as fw:
    writer = csv.writer(fw)
    writer.writerow(('Level', 'Column'))
    for k, v in res.items():
        writer.writerow((k, sum(v)))
```

Using `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv') 
df = df.groupby('Level', as_index=False)['ColumntoSum'].sum().rename(columns={'ColumntoSum': 'Column'})
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
   Level  Column
0      1      22
1      2      35
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group the rows by level and then obtaining the sum for each row.  The [operator.itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) function can be used to extract column values efficiently.

```python
import csv 
import itertools
import operator


# Define functions to fetch the columns we want
levelgetter = operator.itemgetter(0)
col2sumgetter = operator.itemgetter(1)

with open('data.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    # Skip header row
    next(reader)

    # sort the rows by level (required for groupby)
    sorted_rows = sorted(reader, key=levelgetter)

    # Loop over the groups and sum the values
    for level, group in itertools.groupby(sorted_rows, key=levelgetter):
        total = sum(int(col2sumgetter(row)) for row in group)
        print(level, total)
```